# Pandas adding header to the output file after merging multiple CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import os

file1 = 'https://public.fyers.in/sym_details/NSE_CM.csv'
file2 = 'https://public.fyers.in/sym_details/NSE_FO.csv'
file3 = 'https://public.fyers.in/sym_details/BSE_CM.csv'
CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6
csv_file_list = [file1, file2, file3]
output_file = "/content/output.csv"

for csv_file_name in csv_file_list:
  skipRows = [2022,92805]
  chunk_container = pd.read_csv(csv_file_name, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE, skiprows=skipRows)
  for chunk in chunk_container:
    headerList =["fytoken", "symbol", "instrumentType","lotSize","tickSize","ISIN","tradingSession","lastUpdate","expiryDate","symbolTicker","exchange","segment","scripCode","scripName","scripToken","strikePrice","optionType"]
    chunk.to_csv(output_file,header=headerList, mode="a", index=False)
```

---

I want to merge the three CSV files and add header to the output file.
But it's returning output file at with header at start of each CSV (in the output file).

Comment: Like files are merged but it has headers is it and you don't want that. Correct?

Comment: You are reading the file in chunks and appending `header` for each chunk

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the content in chunks and appending the `header` for each chunk.

Instead, try below:

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = 'https://public.fyers.in/sym_details/NSE_CM.csv'
file2 = 'https://public.fyers.in/sym_details/NSE_FO.csv'
file3 = 'https://public.fyers.in/sym_details/BSE_CM.csv'
CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6
csv_file_list = [file1, file2, file3]
output_file = "./content/output.csv"

headerList = ["fytoken", "symbol", "instrumentType", "lotSize", "tickSize", "ISIN", "tradingSession",
              "lastUpdate", "expiryDate", "symbolTicker", "exchange", "segment", "scripCode", "scripName",
              "scripToken", "strikePrice", "optionType"]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headerList)
df.to_csv(output_file, index=False)

for csv_file_name in csv_file_list:
    skipRows = [2022, 92805]
    with pd.read_csv(csv_file_name, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE, skiprows=skipRows) as chunk_container:
        for chunk in chunk_container:
            chunk.to_csv(output_file, header=None, mode="a", index=False)
```

Here we're creating a csv file with only `headers` beforehand and appending the data read from above URLs to the same file.